# How does AppBar cover the notch area in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I want to know how AppBar in flutter covers the notch area. Looking at the source code the App bar uses NavigationToolbar at its core. But I did not understand how it covers the entire notch area incase there is a notch.

The context behind asking this is I am using NavigationToolbar to achieve a design as shown in the screenshot below. For Android, it is working good but for IOS as in the screenshot, there is a gap at the top next to the notch. Even with

```
SafeArea(top:false)
```

I am not able to cover the area next to the notch. Any suggestions would be helpful.

[image: Notch around area]

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NavigationToolbar` in iOS uses the [CupertinoNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoNavigationBar-class.html) that is compliant with the safearea.

Anyway [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/) forbids the use of interactive controls in the safearea like in your image.

This because iOS users uses the right top corner to open the *control center* and the rest of the top area to open the *notifications*.